# gcc 4.9 error on #define

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor, gcc4.9

The following line

```
#  define always_inline __attribute__((always_inline))
```

is included (from another included file) and complained about by gcc 4.9:

```
inc/compiler.h:98:40: error: '__always_inline__' was not declared in this scope
 #  define always_inline __attribute__((always_inline))
                                        ^
```

Strangely enough, the same header (compiler.h) was included in another source file that compiled successfully. Any ideas? *Edit*: I just ensured that `always_inline` was not pre-#defined. FYI:

```
> g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.9
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.9.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13
Configured with: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/work/gcc-4.9-20140406/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc49 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc49 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.9 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.9 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc49/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-cloog=/opt/local --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc49 4.9-20140406_0'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.0 20140406 (experimental) (MacPorts gcc49 4.9-20140406_0)
```

Comment: You got that error message on the line that defines the macro?

Comment: What happens if you compile a `foo.c` file containing just that one line? Is it possible there are some funny characters on that line? A trailing backslash on the previous line?

Comment: @KeithThompson As I said: the same header was included in previous successful compiles ...

Comment: Yes, but it's worth trying.

Comment: How is it being used? Does `gcc -E` for your file gives correct (expected) substitution of your macro? gcc should never comply about macro that way because, well, it's just a macro.

Answer (score 0):

The compiling is saying the symbol `__always_inline__` is not defined, you are defining the symbol `always_inline`.
My compiler.h (arm\atmel studio) has the define as `#define __always_inline     inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))`